# Why is Titan able to maintain an atmosphere, and not Luna?

Tags: atmospheric-science, moon

I just read [stability of hypothetical lunar atmosphere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9584/stability-of-hypothetical-lunar-atmosphere). From the correct answer, i understand, the low escape velocity from Luna is part of the reason it is unable to retain an atmosphere.

Titan apparently has a comparable escape velocity

- Titan = 2.65 km/sec
- Luna = 2.4 km/sec

; yet Titan maintains an atmosphere.

Why? What have I missed? Does Luna's relative proximity to Sol make the difference?

Comment: Both rody_o, and jefromi hit the right points. I've opted to mark jefromi's reply as correct because it is easier for a layman as me to comprehend

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few differences between Luna and Titan.

One of the primary mechanisms for atmospheric loss is thermal escape. **Titan is much colder**. The particles which escape are essentially the tail of the [Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution), the portion with velocity higher than the escape velocity. This end of the distribution is dominated by an $e^{-E/kT}$ contribution, so as you'd expect, lower temperature means fewer particles with enough kinetic energy to escape. Note also that since we care about escape *velocity*, while the distribution is really about energy, more massive particles won't escape as easily. [Titan's atmosphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Titan) is mostly nitrogen, while [the moon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_the_Moon) is mostly helium and argon. **The helium in the moon's atmosphere is easily lost**, since it's so much lighter.

Another big cause of atmospheric loss is the solar wind. Titan itself doesn't have a magnetic field to protect it from the solar wind, but it does happen to orbit an enormous planet with a magnetic field. **Titan is protected from the solar wind by [Saturn's magnetosphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetosphere_of_Saturn)**. Titan orbits at about 20 $R_S$, while the magnetopause is somewhere between 16 and 27 $R_S$, so Titan is inside the magnetosphere a substantial amount of the time. There are a lot of complications due to passing through the magnetopause, but from what I understand, the net effect is definitely protective. And of course, **Titan is farther from the sun**, so the solar wind is weaker.

Answer (score 9):

My guess would be that since

- Titan is 80% [more massive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_%28moon%29) than Luna, so the escape velocity is somewhat larger as well
- it is a lot colder there -- N$_2$/CH$_4$ molecules moving a lot slower on average
- there is considerably less Solar wind to blow particles from the top layers away

Titan can hold its atmosphere indefinitely.

I haven't done any calculations or so, so you might want to check if hydrostatic equilibrium indeed holds for Titan and its atmosphere, or if it's a transient phenomenon.

Comment: The escape velocity difference appears to be minor; hence my question. 
Titan = 2.65 km/sec
Luna  = 2.4 km/sec

Comment: @Everyone A small difference in escape velocity can make a *big* difference in the loss rates because the loss happens at the end of a exponentially dropping velocity distribution.

Comment: @dmckee: That didn't occur to me ... good point.

Answer (score 0):

The moon did not have an atmosphere to begin with. It was formed out of debris from when a planetoid crashed into the earth. The resulting lava hardened into the moon. Titan naturally formed with an atmosphere.

Comment: The moon *has* an atmosphere: see [the wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_the_Moon). The moon is outgassing all the time, but simply unable to hold it there indefinitely.